# Debug missing keystrokes

Tags: debugging

Something has happened to my Emacs environment that causes keystrokes to be dropped occasionally. It seems to happen more often in `isearch`, or after a week and a couple hundred buffers open.

The missing keys are absent in `view-lossage`. Ideally I'd like to trace all elisp calls, but `(setq edebug-trace t)` doesn't seem to have any effect.

How would you go about debugging lost keystrokes?

Comment: Any pattern? Is it always the same keys? Does it matter how busy your computer is? Do you see the same thing when starting Emacs with `emacs -Q`? (If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.) What is your "Emacs environment"?

Comment: Thanks @Drew, yes I guess bisecting my config is the way to do it. I was hoping that there was a trace-like command I could run to see any patterns or smoking guns. It's different keys; seems to happen more under high load; I'm running Emacs 25.3.1 for OSX.

Comment: After bisecting, turns out `emojify-mode` was the culprit. 

Comment: But issue seems to be resolved after upgrading that package 